# Show that no linear map $F:X \rightarrow \mathbb {K}^{n}$ is injective

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I have some troubles with this exercise.

Let X be an infinite dimensional normed vector space over $\mathbb {K}$ where $\mathbb {K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb {K}=\mathbb{C}$. Let $n\geq 1$ be an integer. Show that no linear map $F:X\rightarrow \mathbb{K}^{n}$ is injective.

I am thinking that I have to show that the null-space of F is different from $\left\{0\right\}$, but I don't have any idea for how to show this.
Or else I am thinking that for $x_1 \neq x_2$ then $F(x_1)=F(x_2)$, where $x_1, x_2 \in X$, but I am not sure how to show this either.

Is there anyone who can help me with this exercise.

Comment: Such a map will necessarily be onto $\mathbb{K}^m$ for some $m\le n$, thus forcing $X$ to be finite-dimensional, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{K}^n$ is injective. Let $x_1,...,x_{n+1}$ linear independent in $X$, $f(x_1),...,f(x_{n+1})$ is dependent. There exists $a_1,...,a_{n+1}$ not all equal to zero such that $a_1f(x_1)+...+a_{n+1}f(x_{n+1})=f(a_1x_1+..+a_{n+1}x_{n+1})=0$, we deduce that $a_1x_1+...+a_{n+1}x_{n+1}=0$ since $f$ is injective and $a_i=0$, since $x_1,..,x_{n+1}$ is independent.  Contradiction.

Comment: I do not get how you conclude that $Fx_i=0$ at the end and claim a contradiction. Shouldn’t your argument rather be “there exists $\{a_i\}_i$ not all **zero** such that $\sum_ia_iFx_i=0$.....and since $\{x_i\}_i$ is linearly independent, then $a_i=0$, hence a contradiction”?

Comment: Tsemo - when you say dependent do you mean that $f(x_1),...,f(x_{n+1})$ is linearly dependent? If so, why is $f(x_1),...,f(x_{n+1})$  linearly dependent?

Comment: because $n+1$ vectors in an $n+1$-dimensional vector space they are linearly dependent.

Comment: The reason why we can let $x_1,...,x_{n+1}$ be linearly independent, is it because that X is an infinite dimensional vector space? And why do we look at 
$x_1,...,x_{n+1}$ and not just $x_1,...,x_{n}$.


Furthermore how do we know that $f(x_1),...,f(x_{n+1})$ is in a $n+1$ dimensional vector space?